# formats of image in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to save an image in different format using opencv and c++.
Have a code for displaying the image and exits when a key is pressed. 
What are the possible formats in which a image in jpeg be displayed and how?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
    if( argc != 2)
    {
    cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);  

    if(! image.data )                             
    {
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display window", image );                 

    waitKey(0);                                          
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I posted an answer, but re-reading you question is difficult to understand which kind of format are you referring to, or whether to save or display an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56&gsc.tab=0):

The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( `Mat::data==NULL` ). Currently, the following file formats are supported:

- Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
- JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Notes section)
- JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Notes section)
- Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Notes section)
- WebP - *.webp (see the Notes section)
- Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm *.pxm, *.pnm (always supported)
- Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
- TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Notes section)
- OpenEXR Image files - *.exr (see the Notes section)
- Radiance HDR - *.hdr, *.pic (always supported)

**Note**

- The function determines the type of an image by the content, not by the file extension.
- On Microsoft Windows* OS and MacOSX*, the codecs shipped with an OpenCV image (libjpeg, libpng, libtiff, and libjasper) are used by default. So, OpenCV can always read JPEGs, PNGs, and TIFFs. On MacOSX, there is also an option to use native MacOSX image readers. But beware that currently these native image loaders give images with different pixel values because of the color management embedded into MacOSX.
- On Linux*, BSD flavors and other Unix-like open-source operating systems, OpenCV looks for codecs supplied with an OS image. Install the relevant packages (do not forget the development files, for example, "libjpeg-dev", in Debian* and Ubuntu*) to get the codec support or turn on the OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS flag in CMake.

**Note**

In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt regarding the formats. In such a scenario the image loaded in one format (say jepg) needs to saved in the directory in two or more other form (say png and tif).

Comment: This code converts to 32 bit format but not to the formats you mentioned  .Mat dest;   //Convert image to 32 bit format
       image.convertTo(dest,CV_32F,6,5);
       namedWindow("window2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
       imshow("window2",dest);// shows the converted image.
       cout<< "destination intensity =" <<(int) dest.at<Vec3f>(2,5)[0]<<endl <<endl;
      imwrite("result.jpg",image);// it will store the image in name "result.jpg" imwrite("result.png",image);// it will store the image in name  "result.png"

Comment: Yes it did help. Thank you